# Android: WebView's method goBack() shows a blank page

Tags: android, android-webview

I have an android application that loads web pages in an activity with a WebView. I am using the retrieving the page manually and using WebView's **loadDataWithBaseURL** to display it on screen. Everything there is fine.

Now, i am trying to override the Back button press to simulate going back in the WebView history stack. I am able to override the Back button press, i can see that there is a history stack in the WebView, i can see that the history url is correct, but when i call WebView's **goBack()** method, it displays a blank page.

Anyone encountered this before or give me a couple of suggestions to proceed from this?

**Edit**: If i use WebView's **loadUrl** method, the Back button with an override works as intended. But why.... If i need to handle this manually, how do i start messing with history pages?

Answer (score 6):

I got the same problem also. I found that the problem went away if I set the historyUrl parameter on the call to loadDataWithBaseURL.

Comment: The parameter name has changed recently to `failUrl`

Comment: what value should we set in historyUrl

Comment: I've tried setting historyUrl to html/urls/wathever, but with no success... Has anyone succeeded with that?

Comment: I've duplicated the url in historyUrl parameter and the problem went away. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you. This is he best answer found after going through dozens of pages, I pointed the historyUrl to the home page of my webview (the first url from were I downloaded my html page as String) then it started working without any problem in Android versions 10+ otherwise it was working only in in android 23+

Answer (score 1):

You should check if the canGoBack() method returns true before calling goBack()

Comment: I am already checking it. From my description in the question above, i am also able to get what the history url is (the page before). When i execute goBack, it shows a blank page.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I've found is to create a Stack<String> and manually manage history

Answer (score 0):

What I noticed is that if the url ends in `.html`, that white screen **appears** when back button is pressed.

On the other hand, if you remove that `.html` from your url - obviously only if this is supported by that website (i.e. the redirection and all is handled properly at the server side and that it doesn't trigger the 404 Page Not Found error), that url will act as your *base* this time and when you press the back button, that white screen **should not appear** this time.

for example: you have to replace
http://example.com/page.html to:
http://example.com/page

Answer (score 0):

The way I deal with this is keeping a local stack pointer to the number of loaded pages after the root page loaded using `loadDataWithBaseURL` . When going back, if my pointer hits 1 I am at root level and reload the root page with  `loadDataWithBaseURL`.

FYI, I use this code in Activities with fragments, so the fragments implement the interface IBackButtonListener which helps me to capture the back button in the main activity and propagate the event to the current fragment. If the fragment returns true it means it has taken care of the event.

IBackbuttonListener.java

```
public interface IBackButtonListener {
    public boolean onBackButtonPressed();
}
```

Fragment that implements IBackButtonListener and has a webview loaded from html data.

```
    private int historyStackPointer = 0;

    ...

         @Override
            public boolean onBackButtonPressed() {
                boolean rtn = false;

                if (webView.canGoBack()) {
                    if(historyStackPointer > 1) {
                        webView.goBack();
                        historyStackPointer--;
                        rtn = true;
                    }else{
                        if(historyStackPointer == 1) {
                            // Reload the html data 
                            webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/", html_data, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
                            historyStackPointer = 0;
                            rtn = true;
                        }else{
                            webView.loadUrl("about:blank");
                            rtn = false;
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    rtn = false;
                }
                return rtn;
            }
```

html_data is a String with the page's html.