# Android2.2 Webview goback issue

Tags: android

I used WebView to launch the webpage of given address and added two buttons i.e BACK and FORWARD to navigate

i used webview.goBack() method to BACK and webview.goForward() to FORWARD,navigation of web pages works fine with the public domain urls like www.google.com but not with local urls like http://localhost

Why does this happen,Any Solution???

Answer (score 1):

Use your system IP address instead of localhost.Android is blocking localhost.Hope this will help.

Comment: Were you able to use your system IP address like (http://xxx.xxx.xx.x for example)

Comment: Yes,i used the system ip address web pages are displayed but navigation of web pages is not working

Comment: please refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3574674/android-webviews-method-goback-shows-a-blank-page

Comment: Thanks UNNI,but the problem still persists. I am unable to resolve it.