# Android blank screen on onBack in a loadDataWithBaseURL

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

Probably it will have a simple solution but I've read many threads here but no way.
In a ListView, if i tap on a row it opens a new Activity. In that activity I make an httpget and I create an html string with what I need from that httpget (a portion of the web page retrieved).

So I simply make a `loadDataWithBaseURL("http://base_path.com/", html, mime, encoding, null)`.

It works as expected and I view the web page with links and images.
Now the problems come... If I tap on an image I see the large image in that windows but once i press the "back" on the phone I see a white page. I know that it is caused by the "null" argument but... what I should put to see the html page again? I tried to put "html" instead of null but I see the html code inside the webview!

This is my `onKeyDown` to override the back button:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    // Check if the key event was the BACK key and if there's history
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && webView.canGoBack()) {
        webView.goBack();
        return true;
    }
    // If it wasn't the BACK key or there's no web page history, bubble up to the default
    // system behavior (probably exit the activity)
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a workaround i made the following activities.

1. removed the onKeyDown function
2. removed the myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

In this way the image loads in the default Android browser and i can close it with the back button.

It is not fine to go outside the WebView but i had no other choices.

Comment: Answer not related to the question. It's a workaround for your specific needs, but not an answer to your question.

Answer (score 7):

I found some information at this answer:
[Android: WebView's method goBack() shows a blank page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3574674/android-webviews-method-goback-shows-a-blank-page)

You need to provide a URL to back into when you call

```
loadDataWithBaseURL("http://base_path.com/", html, mime, encoding, null);
```

You are passing null so defaults to 'about:blank'. Try this instead:

```
String baseUrl = "http://base_path.com/";
loadDataWithBaseURL(baseUrl, html, mime, encoding, baseUrl + filename);
```

Comment: I would like to +100 you

Comment: You are a life saver! I remember reading this in the docs long ago and yet managed to get frustrated for many hours. Finally had a light bulb moment on reading your answer.

Answer (score 1):

As Gadgeteer mentioned passing null on `loadDataWithBaseURL()` will add the `'about:blank'` into the stack of webview history.

To avoid this problem, I clear webview history as soon as I call `loadDataWithBaseURL()` by calling

```
webview.clearHistory()
```

as per document

> **public void clearHistory ()**
>
> ```
> Tells this WebView to clear its internal back/forward list.
> ```

If you call clearHistory() after calling loadDataWithBaseURL() the webview not go back to blank page and `canGoBack()` also return false; because there is no back stack in the webview after clearHistory()

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
webview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/your_html.html");
```

instead of your loadDataWithBaseURL

Comment: so I have to store my "String html" in a file and load it from (for example) the SD card?

Comment: nah, just use a URL. I didn't mean to put file:// . You can just do http://whatevertheURLis.com/whatever

Comment: i know :) but i made the html String because i parse the HTTPGET and i retrieve only the portion of the webpage i need... this is why i need to use the loadDataWithBaseURL. The only problem is that if i tap on a link inside the web page and i press on back key i need to return on the loadDataWithBaseURL page but instead i see a white page. Many thanks.